# Checkin through FB app

Tags: php, facebook

I will be building an FB app. I am new to FB app development. Main feature of it requires checkin through my app. 
Is that possible?
App will also keep track of Checkin and prepare a city wise statistics.
Which API will be better for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Checkin through your app is possible:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Note that this possibility is deprecated, the new way to go is to use a post message and include a checkin. But it´s all in the link.
You should get experienced with Facebook programming first though, especially with the JavaScript SDK and the PHP SDK. Also make sure you read the rules of facebook, or your apps will get blocked and maybe your user too.

Answer (score 1):

check the fb documentation.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/ would be a good start.